# Linker Error while running the iOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, linker-errors

[image]

When i run my project in xcode 8 it shows error as shown in screenshot.

I have tried to replace libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a file with latest file of libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a and all suggested solution on stack. So please anyone can tell me that How can i solve this error ?

I have seen this error question on [Xcode 8 -lCorePlot-CocoaTouch issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340363/xcode-8-lcoreplot-cocoatouch-issue)

But there is no reply from anyone. Therefore i have to ask this question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because of some missing libraries in your project.

Check in your **Build Phases** -> **Link Binary With Libraries**. Any of your **framework** may had been removed from there.

Add it and Clean and Build your project. It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you checking the Library Search Paths. There are instances when you copy or duplicate a target, Xcode decides that it needs to escape any double quotes " with a '\'. Make sure you remove all the \’s - it should look like this -
[image]

Comment: In library search path everything is fine. This is not an issue.